# How to show a counter in linkbutton c#

Tags: c#-4.0

Hi I have a downloadlink button

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnDownLoadList" Text="Download ALL(2)" CssClass="cLinkBtn"      CausesValidation="true" runat="server" OnClick="btnDownLoad_Click" /></td>
```

I need to show the numeric inside(2) dynamically from database in between the brackets. How can this be achieved?

Comment: What do you mean by show ?? 

You want to show how many items you have in the DB and show the amount on the button ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access button from code, e.g., `in Page_Load()` Event and set the value. A dummy code might look like:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int value = GetValueFromDatabase();
        btnDownLoadList.Text = "Download ALL(" + value.ToString() + ")";
    }
```